# knockout.js - Get ViewModel from DOM element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

is is possible to get the binded ViewModel JavaScript object from a given DOM element?

```
ko.applyBindings( gLoginViewModel, document.getElementById("login-form") );
ko.applyBindings( gLoginViewModel, document.getElementById("register-form") );
```

and somewhere else - in rather unrelated code - something like this:

```
var viewModel = ko.getViewModel( formElement );
viewModel.someObservable( someData ); // observable available in all ViewModels
```

it would even be better if I could do something like:

```
var viewModel = ko.getViewModel( someChildElement );
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Knockout has two [utility methods](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) that might help here.

- `ko.dataFor` will return the ViewModel that the element is bound to.
- `ko.contextFor` returns the "binding context" of the current element. The object you get back from this method will return something like:

  ```
  { 
      $data: ...,
      $parents,
      $root
  }
  ```

So if I understand your question, you can probably use `ko.dataFor` here. [Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/CCNtR/10/) using `dataFor`.

Comment: Well they are documented here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html  :)