# Subscribe to bindings of an existing DOM element in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I need to subscribe to an existing binding of a DOM element. As an example, I have the following input element:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <input id="MyInput" data-bind="enable: isEnabled()" />
</div>
```

Now, assuming I only have access to the DOM element, I need to do something like this:

```
var inputElement = $("#MyInput");
var bindings = ko.utils.getBindings(inputElement); // getBindings does not exist
var enableBinding = bindings["enable"];
if (enableBinding != undefined) {
    enableBinding.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (value == false)
            $("#MyDiv").addClass("disabled");
        else
            $("#MyDiv").removeClass("disabled");
    })
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Update:** I've extended the sample so that you see my use case for this: The `div` here is automatically generated by a preprocessor and needs the `disabled` class on it when the input is disabled. It does not work if the attribute is only changed on the input element. The addition/removal must be transparent...

Comment: have you tried `ko.utils.getBindings(inputElement.get(0));`?  At the moment you're passing in the jQuery object, not the element? Edit: Ah, I think you mean `getBindings` itself doesn't exist...?

Comment: I dont need the view model of the element but the exact binding for for example "enable"

Comment: In this example i need to know when the "disabled" attribute has changed...

Comment: Hmm see what you mean...

Comment: Been digging in the guts of knockout, unless I'm missing some utility method somewhere, I think you're going to have to effectively invoke some of the core data-bind processing code to re-parse the data-bind string, then get hold of the data/function/observable for whatever binding you're looking for.  Depends how robust you need the solution to be.  It might be more straightforward if it's always a simple `"enable: isEnabled"` type binding as per your question, but if it's more complex it becomes tricky.

Comment: Perhaps there's another approach, such as a custom binding - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Custom bindings have a built in way to get other bindings on the same element.

Comment: @RicoSuter So just to clarify then - you're not able to use a `data-bind="css: {disabled: !isEnabled}"` binding on the `<div>` itself?

Comment: Hmm, nope, because the div is automatically created and not directly implemented by the user of the component... I also want to hide the fact that the enable binding changes the css class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't do this. There is a reason that getBindings is not a particularly visible function in the Knockout toolkit.

Long answer:  You can, through a bit of indirection, get at the original binding.

HTML:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <input id="MyInput" data-bind="enable: isEnabled" />
</div>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEnabled" />
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    self.isEnabled = ko.observable(true);           
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

var input = $('#MyInput')[0];

function getBinding(element, name) {
    var bindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings(input, ko.contextFor(input));

    return bindings.hasOwnProperty(name) ? bindings[name] : null;
}

var binding = getBinding(input, 'enable');

binding.subscribe(function(value) {
    if (value == false)
        $("#MyDiv").addClass("disabled");
    else
        $("#MyDiv").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/ccLanr2t/11/)

EDIT:  Found a shorter way

Again, if there is any way you can convince your preprocessor to add a CSS observable, do so.  Mucking about with bindings in this manner relies on the particular quirks of Knockout 3.3.0's internal implementation, which can change in future releases.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015497/knockout-js-get-viewmodel-from-dom-element).

In short, you can use

```
var viewModel = ko.dataFor(domElement);
```

to get the viewmodel that is bound to that DOM element. You can then, subscribe to any observables attached to that viewmodel.