# Reading Json data from Knockout.Js using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockout where I get my JSON object using Ajax. My question is how do I use this data in my own javascript code:

I have my mapped item, which is what I  get returned from the ajax.
Example:

```
 MedarbejderId: ko.observable(element.MedarbejderId),
```

MedarbejderId is the Id I need to find the name in my following method.

```
function TranslateMed(i)
{
      console.log("test " + i) // for testing purposes in console.

      for (var key in obj)
      {
          if (obj[key].Value == i)
          {
              console.log("vi er inde");
              return obj[key].Text;
          }
      }

      return obj[0].Text
 }
```

obj is my List of names.  this works fine. My issue comes when i save the Data,

```
$(document).on("click", ".kout-update", null, function (ev) {

        var current = ko.dataFor(this);
        console.log(current);
        current.MedarbejderNavn = TranslateMed(current.MedarbejderId);
        current.Mode("display");
        saveData(current);
    });
```

here my current.MedarbejderId is `c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ua(c[F],arguments[0])&&(c.ia(),c[F]=arguments[0],c.ha()),this;a.l.sc(c);return c[F]}`

I need to get the Value of it instead.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015497/knockout-js-get-viewmodel-from-dom-element could help you.

Comment: I found the answer, i forgot i missed the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was that i needed to treat

```
current.MedarbejderNavn = TranslateMed(current.MedarbejderId);
```

Diffrently, so when i changed it to:

```
current.MedarbejderNavn = TranslateMed(current.MedarbejderId());
```

Comment: Knockout observables are functions, so you need the (parentheses) to get the value.