# How to trigger knockout view model change from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that will change the value of the following input element and trigger the model changes that will change other values on the page:

```
<input type="text"  
  data-bind="value: trade.buyVolume, attr: { readonly: trade.buyMaxEnabled() }" 
  value="0" 
  name="quantity_Buy"
>
```

I can achieve this in the Chrome console using the following line:

```
$('#form_Buy > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > input').prop('value', 6).trigger('change');
```

However when I run the same line from the Chrome extension it changes the value of the *input*, but not the view model and doesn't trigger the other page changes.

I know I need to change the view model value `trade.buyVolume`, but it's not accessible from the Chrome console.

***How can I change the view model value?***

Comment: [knockout.js - Get ViewModel from DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015497/knockout-js-get-viewmodel-from-dom-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the view model value?

By changing the view model value.

```
trade.buyVolume(newValue);
```

Do not modify the DOM in a knockout application. Always modify the viewmodel, and only the viewmodel.

You can use `ko.contextFor(domElement)` to retrieve the binding context for an element. The viewmodel is part of the binding context. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html