# How to update knockout js input field from content script on Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, knockout.js

I am creating my first complex chrome extension using javascript to update an input field on a 3rd party website. After hours of research, I found that knockout js is being used. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754366/how-to-trigger-knockout-view-model-change-from-chrome-extension) I found the answer but it´s not clear to me how to implement it. Here is the input field on the DOM.

```
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled,
            maxlength: 255
    }" name="subscriber_telephone" aria-describedby="notice-HWWKNMI" id="HWWKNMI" maxlength="255">
```

I tried this: `document.querySelector('[name="subscriber_telephone"]').value = value` the value is entered and the view is updated, but when I press on the search button nothing happens. I have read that I need to update the view model but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Change `document.querySelector('[name="subscriber_telephone"]')` to `document.querySelector('[name="subscriber_email"]')`.

Comment: I updated the question. The value is entered but when I click on the search button nothing happens.

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Does the site expose `ko` in `window`? If so, you can do `ko.dataFor(document.querySelector('[name="subscriber_telephone"]')).value("something new")`

Comment: I'm not sure that I've got your question :) Are you going to use knockout.js in your extension? If yes - do not use DOM manipulation, use data binding of KO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of wOxxOm and to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849) answer, I achieved what I wanted.

```
 const inputField =  document.querySelector('[name="subscriber_telephone"]')
    if (inputField ) {
      inputField .focus();
      inputField .select();
      if (!document.execCommand('insertText', false, value)) {
        // Fallback for Firefox: just replace the value
        inputField .value = value;
      }
      inputField .dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
    }
```